# Why this MySQL query is faster without index?

Tags: php, mysql

I am having trouble understanding why my MySQL query runs faster when I change it to use no indexes.

My first query takes 0.236s to run:

```
SELECT 
    u.id, 
    u.email, 
    CONCAT(u.first_name, ' ', u.last_name) AS u_name
FROM
    tbl_user AS u
WHERE
    u.site_id=1
    AND u.role_id=5
    AND u.removed_date IS NULL
ORDER BY 
    u_name ASC 
LIMIT 0, 20
```

My second query takes 0.147s to run:

```
SELECT 
    u.id, 
    u.email, 
    CONCAT(u.first_name, ' ', u.last_name) AS u_name
FROM
    tbl_user AS u USE INDEX () 
WHERE
    u.site_id=1
    AND u.role_id=5
    AND u.removed_date IS NULL
ORDER BY 
    u_name ASC 
LIMIT 0, 20
```

I have a unique index named idx_1 on columns site_id, role_id and email.

The EXPLAIN statement tells that it will use idx_1.

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+-------------------------------------+-------+---------+-------------+-------+----------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys                       | key   | key_len | ref         | rows  | Extra                                              |
+----+-------------+-------+------+-------------------------------------+-------+---------+-------------+-------+----------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | u     | ref  | idx_1,idx_import,tbl_user_ibfk_2    | idx_1 | 8       | const,const | 55006 | Using index condition; Using where; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-------+------+-------------------------------------+-------+---------+-------------+-------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

The table has about 110000 records.

Thanks

**UPDATE 1:**

Below is the list of my table indexes:

```
Name                Fields                      Type    Method
---------------------------------------------------------------
idx_1               site_id, role_id, email     Unique  BTREE
idx_import          site_id, external_id        Unique  BTREE
tbl_user_ibfk_2     role_id                     Normal  BTREE
tbl_user_ibfk_3     country_id                  Normal  BTREE
tbl_user_ibfk_4     preferred_country_id        Normal  BTREE
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Can you repeat the same results on reboot (not just service restart) with the queries executed in the opposite order?

Comment: Have you gone through this yet https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/index-hints.html - Your answer may very well lie in it.

Comment: The first query might write to cache, the second can then read from memory rather than from the disk which is way faster.

Comment: you are selecting from tbl_user but your explain is for user?

Comment: Try and clear your cache and then re-run the query...

Comment: Here are the new times after restarting the service (in order of execution):
Restart 1
- Query 1 : 13.782s (OMG)
- Query 2 : 0.172s

Restart 2
- Query 2 : 0.560s
- Query 1 : 1.361s

Restart 3
- Query 1 : 13.248s
- Query 2 : 0.221s

Comment: I don't think the result is from the cache. Because timing after multiple executions of both queries does not match. I mean if I keep executing query 1 multiple times it always takes 0.23xs and query 2 is always 0.14xs. If the results were from cache then at some point the time taken for execution should match up to some extent.

Comment: Please run optimize table and also please update question to show what your indexes are

Comment: Hi e4c5, I optimised the table but no luck. Added the indexes in the question.

Comment: InnoDB, MyISAM, VARCHARs?

Comment: Table is InnoDB. Columns id is unsigned int and other two columns in the query are varchar.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified which mysql you are using.  Does this explain it

> Prior to MySQL 5.1.17, USE INDEX, IGNORE INDEX, and FORCE INDEX affect only which indexes are used when MySQL decides how to find rows in the table and how to process joins. They do not affect whether an index is used when resolving an ORDER BY or GROUP BY clause.

from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/index-hints.html